# API request is null when using SendAsync

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor

I have a request object below:

```
public class SearchRequest
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "search_value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and a web api endpoint that expects

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("~/api/city/search")]
public SearchResponse Search(SearchRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        var result = _cityService.Search(request);

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

which I call using the following

```
var serialisedRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
```

which serialises the request like `{"search_value":"test"}`.

```
var content = new StringContent(serialisedRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }))
{
    SetupHttpClient(client);

    var fullUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", baseUri, svcEndPoint);


    var request = new HttpRequestMessage { Content = content, Method = HttpMethod.Post, RequestUri = new System.Uri(fullUrl) };

    using (var result = await client.SendAsync(request))
    {
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(content);
        }
     }
 }
```

When I call the API and put a break point in the API controller, the value for Value is null.

Any reason why this would be?

Comment: Maybe you can try `public SearchResponse Search([FromBody]SearchRequest request)`?

Comment: @vernou Value still null. I think it has something to do with the jsonproperty

Comment: Possible, [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) is used by the old deserializer json.net. But from ASP.NET Core 3, the default serializer is the new System.Text.Json. In this case, you need use [
System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyNameAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute).

Comment: Like `[JsonPropertyName("search_value")] public string Value { get; set; }`

Comment: @vernou That's it. Looks like `JsonPropertyName` is the answer here

Comment: Can you specify the ASP.NET Core version and show the class `Startup`?

Comment: @vernou The API is .Net Core 3.1 and the Blazor app that calls it is is also running .NET Core 3.1

Comment: Do not use `using()` on HttpClient.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, can you develop? I don't understand what is a issue to dispose HttpClient.

Comment: https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: @henj holterman has a point but seeing as this is a small application, using doesn’t matter in this case. If it were an application that replied on a lot of calls I’d be different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) is used by the deserializer json.net.But from ASP.NET Core 3, the default deserializer is [System.Text.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json). Then the expected attribute is [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyNameAttribut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute).

In your case :

```cs
public class SearchRequest
{
    [JsonPropertyName("search_value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

From @HenkHolterman comment, it seem the class `SearchRequest` is shared between the client and server.
But the client use json.net and the server use System.Text.Json, then you need specify the two attribute like :

```cs
public class SearchRequest
{
    // To desierialize on the client by json.net
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "search_value")]
    // To desierialize on the server by System.Text.Json
    [JsonPropertyName("search_value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Other solution I advice, it's to use the same json library on the client and the server.

Comment: Actually, I'm afraid I was wrong. I'm still getting null for my request object. Using above DOES pass `{"Value":"test"}` but the API still says that value is null

Comment: It only seems to work when I have both   `[JsonPropertyName("search_value")]` and 
`[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "search_value")]` decorating the attribute.

Comment: Then you have System.Text.Json on one side and NewtonSoft on the other.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I miss the point some code is shared... Can I edit my answer to integrate this information?

Comment: My comment was for @JamesS. The answer is OK.