# "The JSON value could not be converted to Enum in Refit

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, refit

I have one .Net Core Razor pages app which is trying to call a .Net Core API with a class library created using Refit.

I have created one Refit API interface which uses a model with enum as one of the property type.

Here is the interface snippet on the API side: `IPaymentAPI` interface

```
    [Post("/recharge")]
    Task<string> Recharge([Body] RechargeRequest request);
```

Here is the request model: The model contains one simple enum `ELicenseType`.

```
public class RechargeRequest
{
    public ELicenseType LicenseType{ get; set; }
}
```

The ELicenseType:

```
public enum ELicenseType
{
    NotSpecified = 0,
    Standard = 1,
    Commercial = 2
}
```

The API implementation in controller:

```
    [HttpPost("recharge")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Recharge(
        [FromBody] RechargeRequest request)
    {
        Recharge result = await _mediator.Send(_mapper.Map<RechargeCommand>(request));

        return Ok();
    }
```

When calling this Recharge method the Refit is throwing the ValidationApiException:

```
ValidationApiException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
```

And the content is:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-f9178d81421bca438241dd2def43d065-edbd7f210919b24e-00",
  "errors": {
    "$.licenseType": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to ELicenseType. Path: $.licenseType | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 98."
    ]
  }
}
```

It seems that the Refit library does not support Enums in the request or my JSON serializer is misconfigured.

Comment: Can you show the enum `ELicenseType`? Can you show the API action signature?

Comment: Added the requested code. Please review. FYI the breakpoint on the endpoint is not being hit.

Comment: Return 400 and endpoint not hit... Generally is because the attribute [ApiController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api#automatic-http-400-responses) is somewhere.

Comment: Maybe this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68817174/api-request-is-null-when-using-sendasync/68819048#68819048

Answer (score 21):

Do you need to set this config in your `startup.cs`?

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(opt =>
     {
         opt.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
     });
 }
```

Comment: But I don't want to alter the default behavior of my API project, so that it can consume when it is sending int in enum on a container class. How can I send the value which is int instead of enum type name which is string?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a Refit implementation for your API's interface, you can provide an instance of [RefitSettings](https://reactiveui.github.io/refit/).

```
var refitSettings = new RefitSettings
{
    ContentSerializer = new SystemTextJsonContentSerializer(new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
        NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString,
        Converters =
        {
            new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase)
        }
    })
};

var api = RestService.For<IMyApi>(client, refitSettings);
```

I think that will solve your problem.